# ArrayController as itemController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to use an ArrayController as itemController in another ArrayController?

For example having:

```
{{#each item in controller itemController="someOtherArrayController"}}

{{/each}}
```

Comment: Why not just use an ObjectController?